# get values from jsonb postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I got the following jsonb, where I want retrieve the values from the keys: type, status and id. I tried the following but it wont succeed? not sure where it goes wrong. Somebody who could help me out? Tnx in advance!

```
with raw_data(col) as 
(
select '{
    "tools": [
        {
            "type": "toolA",
            "links": {
                "get": {
                    "url": "/toolAget",
                    "method": "GET"
                },
                "post": {
                    "url": "/toolAPost",
                    "method": "POST"
                }
            },
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "id": "7891000"
        },
        {
            "type": "toolB",
            "links": {
                "get": {
                    "url": "/toolBget",
                    "method": "GET"
                },
                "post": {
                    "url": "/toolBPost",
                    "method": "POST"
                }
            },
            "status": "INACTIVE",
            "id": "123456"
        }
    ]
}'::jsonb
)
select 
col -> 'tools' -> 'type',
col -> 'tools' -> 'status',
col -> 'tools' -> 'id'
from raw_data;
```

Comment: `tools` is an array. From which array element do you want to get the values? Please **[edit]** your question and add the expected output as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: I found the solution already. need to use the jsonb_array_elements(col) function! Tnx for the remark!

Answer (score 0):

Using `jsonb_extract_path` to fetch the `tools` array and then `jsonb_to_recordset` to pull out the `id`, `type` and `status` values.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    jsonb_to_recordset(jsonb_extract_path('{
    "tools": [
        {
            "type": "toolA",
            "links": {
                "get": {
                    "url": "/toolAget",
                    "method": "GET"
                },
                "post": {
                    "url": "/toolAPost",
                    "method": "POST"
                }
            },
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "id": "7891000"
        },
        {
            "type": "toolB",
            "links": {
                "get": {
                    "url": "/toolBget",
                    "method": "GET"
                },
                "post": {
                    "url": "/toolBPost",
                    "method": "POST"
                }
            },
            "status": "INACTIVE",
            "id": "123456"
        }
    ]
}'::jsonb, 'tools')) AS x (id integer,
        type varchar,
        status varchar);

 id     | type  |  status  
---------+-------+----------
7891000 | toolA | ACTIVE
123456  | toolB | INACTIVE
```